# How to reset the PrimaryLanguageOverride?

Tags: localization, win-universal-app

I have been going through the process of localizing my apps and in doing so I temporarily set the language to Chinese like this:

```
ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = "zh-CN";
```

However, after commenting out the line and rebuilding / re-deploying, now my app is still stuck in Chinese instead of what my development machine's default language at the OS level (English)!

How do I reset this to go back to the default OS setting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just assign an empty string to the [PrimaryLanguageOverride](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.globalization.applicationlanguages.primarylanguageoverride.aspx) property :

```
ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = string.Empty;
```

> The PrimaryLanguageOverride setting is persisted between sessions. It
>   should not be set each time the app is loaded. It should only be set
>   based on user input presented in settings UI. The property can be read
>   at any time. If the property has never been set, it returns an empty
>   string.

So if you set the property to an empty string, the app will use the default language.